# CLLocationDegrees in UITextField

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextField and I want to print there my GPS position, as a test, I create a position:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D myPos;
myPos.latitude = 38.990603;
myPos.longitude= -1.858964;


NSLog(@"%f %f", myPos.latitude, myPos.longitude);
```

This works, but now, I want to add the value to a UITextView:

```
self.myUITextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%f %f", myPos.latitude, myPos.longitude)];
```

This is an error:

```
Sending 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'double') to parameter of incompatible type 'NSString *'
```

How can I print the CLLOcationDegrees values into a UITextField?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parenthesis are probably throwing things off:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%f %f", myPos.latitude, myPos.longitude)];
```

should probably be:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %f", myPos.latitude, myPos.longitude];
```

Comment: I have to wait! You were fast!